# Passing Variable to Blade Causes increment() to Increment DB Field Twice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my Blade file `article.blade.php` I include another view with a variable.

**Blade**

```
@include('frontend/header', ['page_title' => 'hello' ])
```

**Controller**

```
public function hitCollector($article_id)
{
    $data["article"] = DB::table('selected_articles')
        ->where('published', 1)
        ->where('id', $article_id)
        ->get();

    //collecting hit
    DB::table('selected_articles')
        ->where('id', $article_id)
        ->increment('clicks');

    return view('frontend/article', $data);
}
```

As a result, I am getting DB field '**clicks**' increased twice (+2) but not (+1) for given records. I noticed that doubling stops only if I am removing the `['page_title' => 'hello']` part from my Blade inclusion line.

Any ideas? Bug?

Comment: You should post more of your code - is there a chance your site is actually loading twice / reloading? Is there a chance your selected_articles table contains the id twice? You should start with ensuring your queries are doing what you expect. Are you doing any async calls that might be triggerd from the included frontend/header part?

Comment: I've checked network tab for any 301, 302 redirects - nothing, just one single 200 response without doubling requests. 
And yes, no async calls triggered from header, i am running only foreach loope there through passed data. This is frontend/header.blade.php https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sidmike/73ade4fca5a83d8265c6944c14abd2db/raw/7d7471888c11cd2d1f7697bb8fc8029efd03d78d/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @FrankProvost sorry, this is frontend/article.blade.php  source https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sidmike/73ade4fca5a83d8265c6944c14abd2db/raw/7d7471888c11cd2d1f7697bb8fc8029efd03d78d/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... and the problem was really not in Laravel stuff.
I tail'ed my server's access log and started waiting for the hit number while firing it from browsers url field.

And ...  wolla, ugly, ugly little mistake in header.blade.php like this `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`

leaded to this:

[image]

This explained why including an header made such strange behavior of `increment();`.

Thanks for all for support, and sorry for your time! :(